# Is it possible to create a ,multiline <abbr>?

Tags: html

`<li>&#9679;Definition:Some text <abbr title=" (My very very long definition)" tabIndex={0}>betriebswirtschaftliche Fragen</abbr></li>`

How to force the abbr to break the line. If tis not possible what are my alternatives?

[image]

Comment: [MDN claims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) that everything other than a couple of mobile browsers supports multiline title text just by inserting a newline character.

Comment: When i use white characters it is not working. Is ti because of reactJS?

Comment: I don't know, but if you [edit] your question to show an example of the code you've tried with newlines in, and add the [tag:reactjs] tag if you think it might be relevant, maybe someone will be able to help you.